# lm-sensors can't get CPU/motherboard temperature/fan speed

Tags: ubuntu, temperature, intel-core2

I've installed `lm-sensors` and ran `sensors-detect` successfully. It edited my `/etc/modules` so the needed modules (`lm85`, `i2c-i801` and `coretemp`) would get loaded during startup.
I added also those nice applets to my upper Gnome panel.

But it couldn't get any info. Typing `sensors` at terminal simply gives me zeroed values, except for `cpu0_vid` (always +2.050V), and `coretemp-isa-0000` and `0001` (always 42°C).

Those applets keep saying "*Error updating sensor XXX*", like "*An error occurred while trying to update the value of the sensor CPU Fan located at sensor://lm85-i2c-3-2e/20*", and sensor 'CPU' at `sensor://lm82-i2c-3-2e/32`.

What's happening? All modules are correctly loaded, I presume.  And those sensors reported by the applets I choosed (and renamed, 'cos "CPU Fan" is better than "cpu_fan") by it's `Preferences` dialog.

**[EDIT]**

### `sensors` output

> `lm85-i2c-0-2e`
>   `Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at e000`
>   `V1.5:        +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.32 V)`
>   `VCore:       +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.99 V)`
>   `V3.3:        +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.38 V)`
>   `V5:          +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +6.64 V)`
>   `V12:         +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max = +15.94 V)`
>   `CPU_Fan:       0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM`
>   `fan2:          0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM`
>   `fan3:          0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM`
>   `fan4:          0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM`
>   `CPU Temp:     +0.0°C  (low  = -127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)`
>   `Board Temp:   +0.0°C  (low  = -127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)`
>   `Remote Temp:  +0.0°C  (low  = -127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)`
>   `cpu0_vid:   +2.050 V`
>
> `coretemp-isa-0000`
>   `Adapter: ISA adapter`
>   `Core 0:      +42.0°C  (high = +78.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)`
>
> `coretemp-isa-0001`
>   `Adapter: ISA adapter`
>   `Core 1:      +42.0°C  (high = +78.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)`

Comment: When the device is detected by the kernel, it'll create some files in sysfs that the lm_sensors tools use.  Check that these files exist...it'll also help to determine which address and what chip you actually have.
Goto /sys/bus/i2c/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the sensor-applet and look at the Sensors tab. Not everything reported by the applet is provided by lm_sensors, so first ensure the problem is with a sensors output. In your case, I think it is.

If this is true, run the *sensors* command in the terminal to check if this works fine. If it successfully gives you sensor readings, I'd just reinstall sensors-applet.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove sensors-applet
sudo apt-get install sensors-applet
```

If there's a problem getting the sensor values for the CPU fan and CPU, then you should check support for your particular device at the lm-sensors [devices support](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices) page.

Note, lm-sensors project also provides a [standalone script version of sensors-detect](http://dl.lm-sensors.org/lm-sensors/files/sensors-detect) that is likely to be newer than the packaged version, and might better detect sensors on your machine. It only needs perl to work.

In case you're thinking of re-running *sensors-detect*, I'd first remove the */etc/modules* entries added by the previous run. It should be present in a block with a comment at top that says the entry was added by sensors-detect:

```
# Generated by sensors-detect on xxxx
```

---

**Update:**
It appears that you might not actually have an lm85 chip.

From reading reports of other users who reported similar errors, it appears that your chip is either being wrongly detected or is disabled. Look through this very similar [bug report](http://www.lm-sensors.org/ticket/2182) on the lm-sensors site. In fact, from your comment (*"lm82 0-002e: Starting monitoring"*) it appears your system detected the lm82 chip at boot. This chip should use the lm83 driver module according to [lm-sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices), not lm85.

At this point, I'm not sure if you can get any more meaningful help outside of the lm-sensors team. I'd suggest you check your system's hardware specs to determine the chip that's actually present, and separately open a ticket on the lm-sensors site detailing your problems. They are the experts, and they appear to be incredibly helpful.

Search for lm85-i2c-0-2e and you'll realise that you're not alone in facing this issue.

Comment: I ran the newer script. Now it writes config to `/etc/sysconfig/lm_sensors`. It says to `Copy prog/init/lm_sensors.init to /etc/init.d/lm_sensors for initialization at boot time.`, but I can't find this 'prog/init'! I think I'm supposed to start the lm_sensors service as it tells me to do with this file. =S

Comment: oh, and my processor is supported. i saw in the list the core2 family.

Comment: No don't create /etc/sysconfig/lm_sensors as it asks. Just check if it detected the same set of sensors as what you already have in /etc/modules. Also do `sudo grep -i lm85 /var/log/dmesg` and see if you spot any errors. Do a similar check for i2c. Btw, core2 provides the coretemp readings, which you're getting okay.

Comment: `grep` couldn't find anything about `core2` or `i2c`, but found `lm82 0-002e: Starting monitoring`. And `core2` ALWAYS gives me the same temperature, doesn't matter if its cold or hot. Can I test this kind of thing more deeply?

Comment: See the update to my answer - you may have a more fundamental problem with mis-detection of the sensor.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug, then. Following help on the trac with the developers. Thank you =D